# Get the number of lines in a text file using R

Tags: r, file, text-files

Is there a way to get the number of lines in a file without importing it?

So far this is what I am doing

```
myfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.dat")
myfilesContent <- lapply(myfiles, read.delim, header=F, quote="\"")
for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){
  test[[i]] <- length(myfilesContent[[i]]$V1)
}
```

but is too time consuming since each file is quite big.

Comment: Of course not. You may be able to get an approximate value if you know the size of your file and an average line length.

Comment: If you just want to check the number of lines, using `readLines` instead of `read.delim` should be faster than you're currently getting, or at least speeding up your `read.delim` a bit by setting `colClasses` and `comment.char=""` if appropriate. If you know the number of columns, you can set all but one of the colClasses to "NULL" to stop most of them being read in. I'd go with `system` methods though.

Comment: one other possibility that comes to mind (though it involves reading it in a throw away action) is `sum(stringi::stri_read_raw(some_file)==10)`. It's a super-fast read (no character/line processing at all) and a super-fast comparison. that function is marked as "experimental" though.

Comment: `length(count.fields(file))` could work, but might be slow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you:

- still want to avoid the system call that a `system2("wc"…` will cause
- are on BSD/Linux or OS X (I didn't test the following on Windows)
- don't mind a using a full filename path
- are comfortable using the `inline` package

then the following should be about as fast as you can get (it's pretty much the 'line count' portion of `wc` in an inline R C function):

```
library(inline)

wc.code <- "
uintmax_t linect = 0; 
uintmax_t tlinect = 0;

int fd, len;
u_char *p;

struct statfs fsb;

static off_t buf_size = SMALL_BUF_SIZE;
static u_char small_buf[SMALL_BUF_SIZE];
static u_char *buf = small_buf;

PROTECT(f = AS_CHARACTER(f));

if ((fd = open(CHAR(STRING_ELT(f, 0)), O_RDONLY, 0)) >= 0) {

  if (fstatfs(fd, &fsb)) {
    fsb.f_iosize = SMALL_BUF_SIZE;
  }

  if (fsb.f_iosize != buf_size) {
    if (buf != small_buf) {
      free(buf);
    }
    if (fsb.f_iosize == SMALL_BUF_SIZE || !(buf = malloc(fsb.f_iosize))) {
      buf = small_buf;
      buf_size = SMALL_BUF_SIZE;
    } else {
      buf_size = fsb.f_iosize;
    }
  }

  while ((len = read(fd, buf, buf_size))) {

    if (len == -1) {
      (void)close(fd);
      break;
    }

    for (p = buf; len--; ++p)
      if (*p == '\\n')
        ++linect;
  }

  tlinect += linect;

  (void)close(fd);

}
SEXP result;
PROTECT(result = NEW_INTEGER(1));
INTEGER(result)[0] = tlinect;
UNPROTECT(2);
return(result);
";

setCMethod("wc",
           signature(f="character"), 
           wc.code,
           includes=c("#include <stdlib.h>", 
                      "#include <stdio.h>",
                      "#include <sys/param.h>",
                      "#include <sys/mount.h>",
                      "#include <sys/stat.h>",
                      "#include <ctype.h>",
                      "#include <err.h>",
                      "#include <errno.h>",
                      "#include <fcntl.h>",
                      "#include <locale.h>",
                      "#include <stdint.h>",
                      "#include <string.h>",
                      "#include <unistd.h>",
                      "#include <wchar.h>",
                      "#include <wctype.h>",
                      "#define SMALL_BUF_SIZE (1024 * 8)"),
           language="C",
           convention=".Call")

wc("FULLPATHTOFILE")
```

It'd be better as a package since it actually has to compile the first time through. But, it's here for reference if you *really* do need "speed". For a `189,955` line file I had lying around, I get (mean values from a bunch of runs):

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.007   0.003   0.010
```

Answer (score 22):

You can count the number of newline characters (`\n`, will also work for `\r\n` on Windows) in a file. This will give you a correct answer iff:

1. There is a newline char at the end of last line (BTW, `read.csv` gives a warning if this doesn't hold)
2. The table does not contain a newline character in the data (e.g. within quotes)

I'll suffice to read the file in parts. Below I set chunk (tmp buf) size of 65536 bytes:

```
f <- file("filename.csv", open="rb")
nlines <- 0L
while (length(chunk <- readBin(f, "raw", 65536)) > 0) {
   nlines <- nlines + sum(chunk == as.raw(10L))
}
print(nlines)
close(f)
```

**Benchmarks** on a ca. 512 MB ASCII text file, 12101000 text lines, Linux:

- `readBin`: ca. 2.4 s.
- @luis_js's `wc`-based solution: 0.1 s.
- `read.delim`: 39.6 s.
- **EDIT**: reading a file line by line with `readLines` (`f <- file("/tmp/test.txt", open="r"); nlines <- 0L; while (length(l <- readLines(f, 128)) > 0) nlines <- nlines + length(l); close(f)`): 32.0 s.

Comment: Just for clarity: Can you provide benchmark timings that show this is (significantly) faster than the OP's own code?

Comment: Here you are. `wc` is the fastest of the three, but not everyone's on Linux.

Comment: Can you explain the while loop you're using with `readLines`? I get about a 10 fold faster result from `readLines` using `length(readLines("myFile.txt"))` than the OP `read.delim` equivalent gives me so was surprised by your benchmarking (although `read.delim` with `colClasses` is also a lot faster than OP).

Comment: I did `f <- file("/tmp/test.txt", open="r"); nlines <- 0L; while (length(readLines(f, 1)) > 0) nlines <- nlines + 1L; close(f)` - it tries to get the next single line from the file (`readLines` returns a character vector of length 0 if there is nothing more to read). The benchmarks will depend i.a. on the file size and operating system (I'm using Linux)

Comment: are you sure? For me (R3.0.2, Ubuntu) this isn't giving the correct answer (always gives `1`). The benchmark difference I was talking about was that for me, OP read.delim and my readLines were very different, whereas in the solution above they're similar so I was just curious about that :)

Comment: sorry, edited version works (I guess the one in the post should be the same as it though, instead of with n=128?).

Comment: for n=1 I got even worse results :)

Comment: Yeah ok, for me 128 wasn't giving the right result but I think I missed that you had swapped `+ 1L` for `+ length(l)`! I still think just `length(readLines("test.txt"))` would be faster and simpler, but it's not as fast as your readBin so it doesn't really matter :P Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: BTW, try to `readLines` a really huge file and see what happens. :)

Answer (score 21):

I found this easy way using R.utils package

```
library(R.utils)
sapply(myfiles,countLines)
```

[here is how it works](https://rdrr.io/cran/R.utils/man/countLines.html)

Comment: Good option actually but user might not be able to use this.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe I am missing something but usually I do it using length on top of ReadLines:

```
con <- file("some_file.format") 
length(readLines(con))
```

This at least has worked with many cases I had. I think it's kinda fast and it does only create a connection to the file without importing it.

Comment: It can even be written in one-line:  `length(readLines("some_file.format"))`. This also removes the necessity to close the file again. But the problem here is that this reads the whole file into memory, which the asking person does not want.

Answer (score 12):

Here is another way with CRAN package [`fpeek`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=fpeek), function `peek_count_lines`. This function is coded in C++ and is pretty fast.

```
library(fpeek)
sapply(filenames, peek_count_lines)
```

Comment: this method was about twice as fast for me compared to `countLines`

Comment: @Patrick Yes, it *is* fast. I had coded my own line counting function in C and it's about 1% or 2% faster.  This one is on CRAN and I don't believe it's possible to do much better.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using linux, this might work for you:

```
# total lines on a file through system call to wc, and filtering with awk
target_file   <- "your_file_name_here"
total_records <- as.integer(system2("wc",
                                    args = c("-l",
                                             target_file,
                                             " | awk '{print $1}'"),
                                    stdout = TRUE))
```

in your case:

```
#
lapply(myfiles, function(x){
                         as.integer(system2("wc",
                                            args = c("-l",
                                                     x,
                                                     " | awk '{print $1}'"),
                                            stdout = TRUE))
                      }
                  )
```

Comment: Will this not be "time consuming for large files"?

Comment: I don't know of other way to do that within R. System call will transfer the control to the system, it will go as fast as the system goes with wc and awk. Finally, R is great for fast prototyping and visualizing data. If speed is a concern, then I would work with c++, but this will take more time to programm

Comment: system2("wc", args = c("-l", "<file name>")) works on Windows

Comment: @LMc Glad to know that, thank you. Windows seems to be getting more "linux compatible".