# Reading in very, very large NDJSON

Tags: r, json, ndjson

I have a 33GB NDJSON file I need to read into a data.table in R. It's gzipped into a 2GB file, ideally I would like to keep it compressed.

The structure isn't so important except that (when imported via `jsonlite::stream_in`), the data I need are in only a few simple columns. The vast majority of the weight of the data is held in `list`s within three columns I want to discard as soon as possible.

My two challenges are: how can I parallelize the read-in, and how can I limit memory usage (right now my worker on this file is using 175GB memory)?

What I'm doing now:

`dt.x <- data.table(flatten(stream_in(gzfile("source.gz"))[, -c(5:7)]))`

Ideas:

Maybe there is some way to ignore a portion of the NDJSON during `stream_in`?

Could I parse the `gzfile` connection, eg with regex, before it goes to `stream_in`, to remove the excess data?

Can I do something like `readLines` on the `gzfile` connection to read the data 1 million lines per worker?

EDIT: If at all possible, my goal is to make this portable to other users and keep it entirely within R.

Comment: This might be a good case for [Apache Drill via sergeant](https://rud.is/books/drill-sergeant-rstats/reading-a-streaming-json-ndjson-data-file-with-drill-r.html)

Comment: Thanks @alistaire, unfortunately my goal for this project is to do this all in R - it needs to be exportable as a script that can simply be used by other teams to process similar data sets.

Comment: Short of @alistaire's suggestion, I think this is a likely candidate for a `jq` pipe, something like `gzip -c file.ndjson.gz | jq <somepattern>`. This is likely the most memory-efficient way you will be able to find, and the fastest (assuming that `jq` is fast, which I believe). It requires a simple installation of the [`jq` utility](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and likely an R call to `stream_in(pipe(...))` or such.

Comment: There is the [`jqr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jqr/index.html) package that might be of use, but I don't know if it can read from a compressed file.

Answer (score 2):

### Using jqr with readr

Here is a transcript illustrating how to use jqr to read a gzipped NDJSON (aka JSONL) file:

```
$ R --vanilla
> library(readr)
> library(jqr)
> read_lines("objects.json.gz") %>% jq('.a')
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
>
```

Using `read_file()` yields the same result.  Since these functions must unzip the entire file, the memory requirements will be substantial.

### Reading each JSON entity separately

Since the file is NDJSON, we can drastically reduce the amount of RAM required by reading in one JSON entity at a time:

```
con = file("objects.json", "r");
while ( length(line <- readLines(con, n = 1)) > 0) {
   print( line %>% jq('.a') );
}
```

### jq

There are probably better ways to use jqr, but if the goal is both space and time efficiency, then it might be best to use the command-line version of jq.

### Count

If you need to count the number of lines in the (unzipped) file beforehand, then to save memory, I'd probably use `system2` and `wc` if possible; all else failing, you could run a snippet like so:

```
n<-0;
con = file("objects.json", "r");
while (TRUE) {
   readLines(con, n = 1);
   if (length(line) == 0) { break; }
    n <- n+1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @peak. I'm struggling a bit to read this output into a pre-allocated data.table, could you please add that to the example? Would also be great if I can read the number of line from the connection first to know how long the allocation should be. Thank you!

Comment: Updated. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456170/get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file-using-r